# Does importing one function require loading the whole library?

Tags: javascript, import

I have seen posts on StackOverflow where people are saying "Those features can be implemented easily without using `lodash`".

Sure, it takes time to install libraries but when you

```
import { throttle } from 'lodash'
```

Does this import slow down the page because `lodash` is a big library? Or is it OK because I am only importing `throttle`?

Don't focus on `lodash` specifically but think of it as some huge library and I am trying to use only one function from it.

p.s. I am using React (created with CRA) so bundler is webpack by default

Comment: @ggorlen i'm using react, started my project with create-react-app so webpack i guess

Answer (score 2):

If you're building this code with something like webpack, rollup or some other tool that converts modules into a single script file, what will be pushed to the client will depend heavily on what tool you're using. A simple build tool would simply output the whole of lodash onto the output script; whereas something like rollup (and maybe webpack too?) do some complicated things to trim libraries down to just the parts you're using. Of course, if the `throttle` function depends on other parts of lodash, those other parts will also have to be included.

If this is module code running on the client (if it were `import {...} from "./lodash.js"` or if it used the still-experimental [import maps](https://github.com/WICG/import-maps)), things are more complicated than that. The browser will of course have to read the entire `./lodash.js` file, otherwise it won't be able to find the function. But it's my understanding that the contents of the functions themselves won't be even fully processed until they're used.

Comment: The term you are looking for is "tree shaking" https://www.sumcumo.com/en/tree-shaking-an-introduction